# fail to pass shared_ptr<Derived> as shared_ptr<Base> reference

Tags: c++

In the following code, I want to pass `shared_ptr<Derived>` as a `shared_ptr<Base>&` argument, but failed.

Error says,

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::shared_ptr<Base>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr<Base>'
```

so looks like I can only pass `shared_ptr<Derived>` as `const` argument, but this is not what I want to do, how to pass as `non-const`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void say() {
    std::cout << "I'm Base class" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void say() {
    std::cout << "I'm Derived class" << std::endl;
  }
};

void foo(std::shared_ptr<Base>& obj) {
  obj->say();
}

int main() {
  auto base = std::make_shared<Base>();
  foo(base);

  auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
  foo(derived);
}
```

Comment: as `foo` doesn't modify `obj` why can't `obj` be `const`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, in this example it's fine to be const. But my real code requires a non-const.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which shows the actual problem you are trying to solve, the solution to the code you've posted is to make `obj` `const`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, but that conversion results in a temporary object - which can't be bound to a non-`const`-qualified reference (as it's the case for `foo`'s parameter).

That being said, it looks like `foo` has nothing to do with ownership. It's then preferred to pass parameters as references, not wrapped into a smart pointers (passing `std::shared_ptr<T>&` should only be done when a copy *might* be made from within a function, and if you always take a copy, just pass by value). For your examle:

```
void foo(Base& obj) {
  obj.say();
}
```

called like the following.

```
auto base = std::make_shared<Base>();
foo(*base);

auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
foo(*derived);
```

Note the dereferencing of both shared pointer (`*base` and `*derived`). However, if a copy is intended, pass by value (which works when passing a temporary)

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<Base> obj) {
  //                           ^^^ increases refcount
  obj->say();
}
```

and let the calling syntax as it is.

Comment: It *might* be useful to add a `template <typename T> auto foo(T&& p) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<decltype(foo(*p))>>, decltype(foo(*p))> {  foo(*p); }`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The problem is in my real code, I have store the pass-in obj into a `map`, and by design, the map value is Base class ptr, not object. And in order to use the polymorphism, I think that's the reason why  the map value is pointer.

Comment: I just realized that polymorphism also works if it's reference. But if pass by value, I need to be sure the copy constructor is properly defined, which might not be the case in my real code though.

Comment: Passing class instances with `virtual` member functions by value is actually quite dangerous, you might want to search for "object slicing" for more on that topic. `std::shared_ptr` is different here, as it stores a pointer internally.